# Display foreign key value instead of key using Angular

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I created two(2) tables
1. services: name, service_type(id from service_type)
2. service_type: id, name

I am using Angular7 to get endpoints from Laravel API. I want to display name (value and not key) from service_type table. services is the main table.

I have created the model.ts, service.ts component.ts and component.html

model

```
export class Services {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    service_type: number;
  }
```

service

```
  getServices (): Observable<Services[]> {
    return this.http.get<Services[]>(apiUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(services => console.log('Fetch services')),
        catchError(this.handleError('getServices', []))
      );
  }

  getService(id: number): Observable<Services> {
    const url = `${apiUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Services>(url).pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log(`fetched service id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Services>(`getService id=${id}`))
    );
  }
```

component.ts

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'service_type'];  
  data: Services[] = [];
  isLoadingResults = true;  

  constructor(private api: ServicesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.api.getServices()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.data = res;
        console.log(this.data);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      });
```

component.html

```
      <tr  *ngFor="let datas of data">
          <td>{{datas.name}}</td>
          <td>{{datas.service_type}}</td>
        <td>
```

In

> {{datas.service_type}}

which is coming from another table called service_type, I want to display the value (name) and not key (id)

Comment: so from laravel get data with service_type and here display {{service_type.name}} if you have one to one relationship. if possible show your laravel code also

Comment: It is one to many

Comment: For one to many use can show comma separated value